# Can I set framecount to image .gif in Livecode?

Tags: animated-gif, livecode

I have image file .gif. My image have 5 frames and I want to loop with 1 to 3. Frame 4 and 5 I will play when I click. Can I do it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to do it in LiveCode with an animated gif is to set the frame manually - see answer below  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short example that has 2 modes;

- mode 1 plays frames 1 - 3
- mode 2 plays frames 4 - 5
- when the card opens, it starts with mode 1
- clicking the image switches to mode 2

All the code is from the card script..

```
local sFrameStartA, sFrameEndA, sMode, sFrame


on openCard
   -- tuen off automatic animation - we will set the frames manually
   set the repeatCount of image "MyImage" to 0

   -- mode 1 (normal) frames 1 - 3
   put 1 into sFrameStartA[1]
   put 3 into sFrameEndA[1]

   -- mode 2 (frame 4 - 5) after click
   put 4 into sFrameStartA[2]
   put 5 into sFrameEndA[2]

   put 0 into sFrame
   put 1 into sMode

   -- start animation
   send "animate" to me in 0 millisecs
end openCard


on animate
   -- animate : next frame
   add 1 to sFrame

   -- check the frame number is valid - if not, reset to the start frame
   if sFrame < sFrameStartA[sMode] or sFrame > sFrameEndA[sMode] then
      put sFrameStartA[sMode] into sFrame
   end if

   -- update the image's frame
   set the currentFrame of image "MyImage" to sFrame

   send "animate" to me in 500 millisecs
end animate


on mouseUp
   -- clicking the image will switch to mode 2 - frames 4-5
   if the short name of the target = "MyImage" then
      put 2 into sMode
   end if
end mouseUp
```